# Updating joined queries with ADO

Tags: delphi, ado, join

I have a select query that joins 3 tables to display information. If I want to update a field is do

`ADOQuery.Edit.

<Set fields Values>

ADOQuery.Post`.

I get the following error howwever **'Insufficient key column information for updating or refresing'** and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Pieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this OnCreate:

```
YourADODataSet.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'YourTable';
```

This will let the Engine send only one (instead of two) query from joined tables.

Comment: Thanks! This does work. You must however know the table you want to update before activating the data set.